# Where to put loaded packages and user defined functions in a shiny app script?

Tags: r, shiny

so I'm building a shiny app and when I deploy it to shinyapps.io I get several errors. I suspect the organization of my app script is faulty because I include the "library(package)" commands in the script, as well as all my user defined functions. Should I be placing the loading of packages and my used defined functions in a separate script from the app? and if so, how can I do it?
Thanks so much for any response in advance

Comment: Put it at the top of `global.R` if you have one or at the top of `ui.R`.

Comment: the thing is I have all the app inside a single script, and it worked and deployed fine before having all the loading of packages and user defined functions. I don't know how to operate with more than one file in shinny

Comment: Put it at the top of everything in that file - `app.R` I guess. Also try testing your app locally in a fresh R session.